# Replacing preg_replace by preg_replace_callback is giving me a warning

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback, vqmod

This is my code.

```
private function _checkMatch($modFilePath, $checkFilePath) {
        $modFilePath = str_replace('\\', '/', $modFilePath);
        $checkFilePath = str_replace('\\', '/', $checkFilePath);

        $modFilePath = preg_replace('/([^*]+)/e', 'preg_quote("$1", "~")', $modFilePath);
        $modFilePath = str_replace('*', '[^/]*', $modFilePath);
        $return = (bool) preg_match('~^' . $modFilePath . '$~', $checkFilePath);
        return $return;
}
```

I changed preg_replace to preg_replace_callback but it is giving me the following error.

`Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, 'preg_quote("$1", "~")', to be a valid callback`

I'm currently using opencart version 1.x.x

Any one can help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

You need to use the valid callback as  the second argument. You can use function or it name as string:

```
$modFilePath = preg_replace_callback('/[^*]+/', function ($matches){
    return preg_quote($matches[0], "~");
}, $modFilePath);
```

I have deleted unsecured `e` modifier and replaced it to a valid callback for `preg_replace_callback` function.

Also with Old version of PHP you need to add function statement below your code

```
function myCallback($matches){
    return preg_quote($matches[0], "~");
}
```

And then use `preg_replace_callback('/[^*]+/', 'myCallback', $modFilePath);`